# segue back without losing previous information

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, segue

So I have two scenes...the first one has 2 input text fields.  I enter information into the first field before proceeding to the next scene.  The next scene generates information which I need to use back in the first scene to enter in the second text field.  Every time i segue back to the first scene the first string of information is cleared.  I cant simply use the back button, i need to use prepareforsegue so im curious if there is any way to input my text information in scene 1, segue to scene 2 (generate other information) and segue back to scene 1 without losing the information previously entered?

I hope this is enough information.  Thanks in advance.

EDITED

Here is some of my code.

inputMilesViewController.h (FIRST VIEW)

```
@property  (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *myTodayButton;
```

(myTodayButton segues to dvc - prior to segue myTodayButton.titleLabel.text equals     "TODAY")

dvc.m (SECOND VIEW)

```
- (IBAction)myNewSelectDate:(id)sender {

 inputMilesViewController *classInstance = [[inputMilesViewController alloc] init];

[classInstance changeButtonText:[_myNewDatePicker date]];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

inputMilesViewController.m (FIRST VIEW)

```
-(void) changeButtonText:(NSDate*) dateForInput{
NSLog(@"The button is titled %@", self.myTodayButton.titleLabel.text);

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d,''yy"];

NSString *formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:dateForInput];
```

...
   ...
(here is where I try to change the text of the button to read as formattedDateString however the NSLog indicates that the button text is now (null).

Comment: Either keep a reference to the second view so that it doesn't get released (you can grab the reference in the `performseguewithidentifier` method), or save the data with something like `NSCoding` and reload the fields every time.

Answer (score 1):

NEW EDIT

**Add the import at the top of `inputMilesViewController.m`**

```
// At the top with the other #imports
#import "dvc.h"
```

also I recommend learning Object Orientation before going into iOS. Its a key part of it. Its not hard, but definitely essencial.

Add this code to your project.
In `inputMilesViewController.m` add

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    [segue.destinationViewController setClassInstance];    
}
```

In `dvc.h` add this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) inputMilesViewController *classInstance;
```

In `dvc.m` add this:

```
@synthesize classInstance = _classInstance;

- (IBAction)myNewSelectDate:(id)sender {

    // Removed this line
    //inputMilesViewController *classInstance = [[inputMilesViewController alloc] init];

    [self.classInstance changeButtonText:[self.myNewDatePicker date]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

So as I said in the comments, what this code will do is give your string to the original fisrtViewController, and not a new one that you just created. To achieve this you create the property `classInstance` and make it a reference to the original viewController.

Quick tip: Make you class names start with uppercase so you can differentiate them from variables. So in this case: `InputMilesViewController` and `Dvc`.

Also it seems to me you are not very familiar with object oriented programming. I recommend you try to learn more about that and about the MVC model. Both are key part of programming for iOS.

If it still doesnt work tell me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks so much for the dismissViewController idea. Exactly what I was looking for. Iif I am using the dismissViewController and I need to pass that information from 2nd view to first would I still use prepareForSegue even though I am not technically using a segue?  My issue now Is that I am trying to take the information (NSString) from the 2nd scene and use it in the first scene to change the text of a button.  I am having a hell of a time trying to figure that out as well.  Ive been using "[_myTodayButton setTitle:@"TODAY" for State:UIControlSateNormal".  No luck there.  not sure why.

Comment: I also tried _myTodayButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:formattedDateString];

Comment: I'll change my answer of sending info from the secondScene to the firstScene to make it easier

Comment: hey.  thanks again for the response.  I probably should have clarified, I was successfully able to get the data to the firstScene but now I am just trying to get the button text to take it.  I did an NSLog of the data to make sure it came in correctly but somehow my button is being stubborn.  I have it set up in my .h as a IBOutlet UIButton *myTodayButton; theoretically shouldnt i be able to set the text using the code i entered in my last comments? thanks again for your help! sorry to keep comin' at ya.

Comment: I just tried to print the current title of the button and its coming out as null.  what am i doing wrong here? can i not access the button text from within an instance method? maybe thats my issue

Comment: Are you sure the IBOutlet is connected properly? The gray circle on the left of the outlet should have a small dark circle inside it. Also, try to use `[myTodayButton setTitle:yourString forState:UIControlStateNormal];`. Are you creating the IBOutlet with a property? or just a variable?

Comment: yea, the IBOutlet is definitely connected.  When I tried to print the button text in viewDidLoad it had a value (TODAY), but when I attempt the same in my instance it comes out as null.

Comment: after playing for a while it seems as though no matter where i try to access it, my label is turning to null sometime after i call for the second view, and before coming back to the first.  It turns to null and is not accessible to change the text.  going crazy

Comment: Show me some of your code. Since its just 2 view controllers it shouldn't be much. Post it in the original question. Its a UILabel or a UIButton you want to set the string?

Comment: I added some code above.  This is a UIButton, although I tried using a label as well and had the same problem.  Thanks again

Comment: Here is what you are doing wrong: On the second view controller you are creating a brand new inputMilesViewController and giving this new ViewController you string. Thats why when you go back to the original inputMilesViewController the string isnt there. They are 2 different viewControllers.

Comment: In `- (IBAction)myNewSelectDate:(id)sender`. Instead of creating a new  instance of `inputMilesViewController` you want to use a reference to the original view controller that called the second one.

Comment: added another more specific edit to my answer. With the code I provided it should work, if you want to understand better what I did or it simply doesnt work, please tell me.

Comment: I copied the code into my project but received "No known instance method for selector 'setClassInstance' in my inputMiles... .m   ??  and by the way you are very right about me not being familiar with object oriented programming. This program is my very first attempt at programing in any capacity so it is definitely a learning experience.

Comment: Pretty sure you forgot the synthesize. Added another line to answer.

Comment: Did you put the import? Its on the top of my answer. The new edit.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pedros. It sounds like you're doing this wrong. You may be using a segue to get from vc1 to vc2 and then another segue to get from vc2 to vc1 - and that is wrong! It's wrong because a real segue creates a new view controller instance. So you are not coming back to the same vc1 you left earlier; instead, you're making a completely new vc1 and going on to that! That's why the fields are empty; it's a totally new clean view controller.

Instead, what you want to do is do a true segue out and an "exit" (or "unwind") segue coming back. This is a new iOS 6 feature. I have some examples here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples

In particular, look at the four examples whose names begin "ch19p560" and "ch19p561". These show how to hand information from vc1 to vc2 as you segue, and then how to hand information from vc2 back to the same vc1 instance as you unwind back. And they illustrate unwinding to various degrees (e.g. jumping back several view controllers) and in various situations.